# how to insert the check and the value of the checkbox?

Tags: c#

How to insert the check and the value of the checkbox and also help me to read it to checkbox1 = checkbox1, so on so forth and name = textbox using oledbreader thanks

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string n = "";
    string n2 = "";
    string n3 = "";
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        n= "Basketball";
    }
    if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        n2 = "Cooking";
    }
    if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
    {
        n2 = "Reading";
    }

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "insert into RecordC ([Select], [Name]) values (@Select, @Name)";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox1.Checked);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox2.Checked);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox3.Checked);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n3);


        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!");
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

[image: and here is my table]

Comment: You have only two parameters. Don't add the same parameter 3 times. And before of that decide which value you want to store and use the same variable.

Comment: `[Select]` and `[Name]` are terrible names for anything database related.  You are currently adding six parameters when you only have two.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to insert 3 records or not. What if the one of checkboxes is not selected?

Comment: i want all 3 record to my database. if checkbox is not selected then record the select = 0 and name of checkbox to database . then i need to read it the record using oledbReader

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert 3 records, so your query should be:

```
 string query = "insert into RecordC ([Select], [Name]) values (@Select1, @Name1),(@Select2, @Name2),(@Select3, @Name3)";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select1", checkBox1.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select2", checkBox2.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select3", checkBox3.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name1", n);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name2", n2);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name3", n3);
```

**EDIT:**

As Steve says first of all handle your catch (don't swallow any exception but better log it. Also,  the above statement might be be syntactically wrong (it is SQL Server based).
In any case, the exception trace will guide you through the steps for correcting the query.

Comment: I am pretty sure that syntax is not valid for MS-Access.

Comment: Because you have an empty catch. Remove it and you will see the error.

Comment: i use your code but i got error Missing Semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement 

`catch  (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox1.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox2.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n2);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select", checkBox3.Checked);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", n3);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: the value of checkbox1 and checkstate of checbox1 save triple

Comment: add this  `catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw ex;
           }` and find out what the problem is.

Comment: no problem or error. but same value and checkstate of checkbox1 or `@Select` & `@Name`

Comment: The second query will have four parameters and the last query will have six parameters.  You have to *Clear* the paremeters after you run the query if you are going to re-use the cmd object.